# Maintaining a list and interpolation of a map

Tags: list, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, interpolation

I am trying to create a voltage colour map and if I want to do so, I have to maintain 3 different lists that have 3 different values used. These 3 values are called: peak, X3 and Y3 (as seen in the code below). Previously I had a problem updating the list as it inserted new values but that was solved by including a `try:` `except:` block. The code looked as follow after the inclusion of the`try:` `except:` block:

```
for k in range(elec_array.nb_chan):
    print "electrode number", k
    print "The value of act info is", act_info.nb_act[k]
    try:
        if (act_info.nb_act[k]) >0:
             #find the maximum voltage for the set of samples of each channel
             max_V.insert(k,np.max(array_data[:,k]))
             #find the minimum voltage for the set of samples of each channel
             min_V.insert(k,np.min(array_data[:,k]))
             dif = ((((max_V[k] - min_V[k])/(4096.0))*10.0)/
                    elec_array.chan[k].gain) * 1000
             #then compute the difference between the max and min to find the
             #peak-to-peak value
             peak.insert(k,dif)
             X3.insert(k, elec_array.chan[k].x)  #get the coordinates
             Y3.insert(k, elec_array.chan[k].y)
             aa=aa+1
    except IndexError, ValueError:
        Z2as[k] = k #Identify the broken electrode which will be painted white
        print k
        pass
```

When I print all k values and all act_info.nb_act[k] values I can see that all values of act_info.nb_act[k] have a number that is bigger that zero so it should go back into the if statement and insert the numbers but it does not. This are the values that I printed:

```
electrode number 0
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 1
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 2
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 3
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 4
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 5
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 6
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 7
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 8
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 9
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 10
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 11
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 12
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 13
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 14
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 15
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 16
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 17
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 18
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 19
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 20
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 21
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 22
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 23
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 24
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 25
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 26
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 27
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 28
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 29
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 30
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 31
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 32
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 33
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 34
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 35
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 36
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 37
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 38
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 39
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 40
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 41
The value of act info is 2
electrode number 42
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 43
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 44
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 45
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 46
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 47
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 48
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 49
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 50
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 51
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 52
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 53
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 54
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 55
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 56
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 57
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 58
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 59
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 60
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 61
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 62
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 63
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 64
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 65
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 66
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 67
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 68
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 69
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 70
The value of act info is 1
electrode number 71
The value of act info is 2
electrode number 72
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 73
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 74
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 75
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 76
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 77
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 78
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 79
The value of act info is 2
electrode number 80
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 81
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 82
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 83
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 84
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 85
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 86
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 87
The value of act info is 2
electrode number 88
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 89
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 90
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 91
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 92
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 93
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 94
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 95
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 96
The value of act info is 3
electrode number 97
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 98
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 99
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 100
The value of act info is 3
electrode number 101
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 102
The value of act info is 0
electrode number 103
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 104
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 105
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 106
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 107
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 108
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 109
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 110
The value of act info is 4
electrode number 111
The value of act info is 4
```

When I print k inside the exception this is the output that I get:

```
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
```

Meaning that the last nine electrodes are shown to be not functioning.

The output of this whole code was:

[image]

If I observe the picture, I see that most of the electrodes are black and nine are white which indicates that nine are broken. This is not true because when I observed the data only one electrode is broken. So I presume when the values are being inserted into the list, the exception gets called shows the first broken electrode and then it seems to not include the following values of the list thinking that they are broken electrodes. Although if I have many broken electrodes showing I interpolate over them to get a map that is full of colour (the interpolator is not the problem). I would like to know how I can make the code keep entering values after the first real broken electrode hence showing one white electrode and the rest being black. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is the full question @awbemauler

Comment: Instead of presuming what's happening, you should print the values of k in the except block, so we'll know what's happening.

Comment: @saulspatz I just revised the question and included the values of k, which tells me what I have presumed.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.  Are you certain that the other arrays have values for these indices?  For example, is elec_array.chan[104] defined?  How about array_data[104]?  Perhaps the error occurs earlier in the code.

Comment: @ saulspatz I printed all the values of act_info.nb_act[k] to show you that all the values of the electrodes have a number bigger than zero except 103 which is zero. This means that after the 103rd electrode the code should go into the if statement and execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by printing inside the exception (as seen in the question above), I found that values 103 to 111 are displayed as broken electrodes (which they shouldn't because they have values). The only electrode that has a value of zero (as seen in the question above) is electrode 102 (which is the electrode that was broken).
So to solve this, I have to change the code to the following:

```
for k in range(elec_array.nb_chan):
    try:
        if (act_info.nb_act[k]) >0:
          max_V.insert(k,np.max(array_data[:,k]))#find the maximum voltage for the set of samples of each channel
          min_V.insert(k,np.min(array_data[:,k]))                     #find the minimum voltage for the set of samples of each channel
          dif = ((((max_V[k] - min_V[k])/(4096.0))*10.0)/elec_array.chan[k].gain)*1000
          peak.insert(k,dif)  #then compute the difference between the max and min to find the peak-to-peak value
          X3.insert(k, elec_array.chan[k].x)                          #get the coordinates
          Y3.insert(k, elec_array.chan[k].y)

        else:
          Z2as[k] = k #Identify the broken electrode
          aa=aa+1




    except IndexError, ValueError: #In here all the values of the not broken channels detected as broken receive their values. 
            max_V.insert(k,np.max(array_data[:,k]))#find the maximum voltage for the set of samples of each channel
            min_V.insert(k,np.min(array_data[:,k]))                     #find the minimum voltage for the set of samples of each channe
            dif = ((((max_V[k] - min_V[k])/(4096.0))*10.0)/elec_array.chan[k].gain)*1000
            peak.insert(k,dif)  #then compute the difference between the max and min to find the peak-to-peak value
            X3.insert(k, elec_array.chan[k].x)                          #get the coordinates
            Y3.insert(k, elec_array.chan[k].y)
            pass
```

When executing this new code the output that I get is:

[image]

Which makes more sence than the previous output.

Thank you very much for everyone's help and I hope this could be helpful for some of you.